# ¿Por qué me marca error al deserializar una Lista de Objetos?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.android, webapi

Tengo una WebApi, donde hay un método que retorna un Json, debo consumir ese método desde una App de Xamarin Android, el método es el siguiente:

```
 public string GetData(DateTime Del, DateTime Al, Guid id)
        {

            List<TablaVales> LstTemp = new List<TablaVales>();
            List<TablaVales> tableV = new List<TablaVales>();
            string conexion = "data source = snare.arvixe.com; initial catalog = ****; user id = ****; password = ****";
            oLogin myLogin = new oLogin();

           cTripleDES des = new cTripleDES();
            String sQuery = String.Format("SELECT promVales.llave, promVales.NumeroVale, promVales.llaveProm, LTRIM(RTRIM(LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(crmCustomers.Numero, ''))) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(crmCustomers.Nombre1, ''))) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(crmCustomers.Nombre2, ''))) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(crmCustomers.Apellido1, ''))) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(crmCustomers.Apellido1, ''))))) AS Nombre, crmCustomers.DireccionCompleta, CrmCustomers.Telefono, CASE WHEN promVales.Status = 1 THEN 'Asignado' WHEN promVales.Status = 2 THEN 'Extraviado' WHEN promVales.Status = 3 THEN 'Utilizado' WHEN promVales.Status = 4 THEN 'Suspendido por Depto. de Crédito' WHEN promVales.Status = 5 THEN 'Cancelado' ELSE 'Este vale no puede ser utilizado' END AS Status, promVales.FechaAsigna, aztiendas.NOMBRE AS TiendaAsigna, promVales.FechaUso, aztiendas_1.NOMBRE AS TiendaUso, Personas.Nombre AS NombreUsuarioUso, LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(login.Nombres, '') + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(login.Apellidos, ''))))) AS AsignadoPor, LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(login_1.Nombres, '') + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(login_1.Apellidos, ''))))) AS UsuarioVenta, promVales.Caja, promVales.Operacion, promMotivos.Nombre AS MotivoValeExtraviado, promMotivos_1.Nombre AS MotivoValeCancelado, promVales.Monto, promVales.MontoAutoriza, promVales.Anticipo FROM promVales LEFT JOIN CrmCustomers ON promVales.llaveProm = crmCustomers.id LEFT JOIN azTiendas ON promVales.llaveTiendaAsigna = azTiendas.llave LEFT JOIN azTiendas AS azTiendas_1 ON promVales.llaveTiendaUso = azTiendas_1.llave LEFT JOIN Personas ON promVales.llaveClienteUso = Personas.llave LEFT JOIN login ON promVales.llaveUsuarioAsigna = login.llave LEFT JOIN login AS login_1 ON promVales.llaveUsuarioVenta = login_1.llave LEFT JOIN promMotivos ON promVales.llaveMotivoPerdido = promMotivos.llave LEFT JOIN promMotivos AS promMotivos_1 ON promVales.llaveMotivoCancela = promMotivos.llave WHERE(DATEADD(DD, 0, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, promVales.FechaAsigna)) BETWEEN '{0}' AND '{1}') AND promVales.llaveProm = '{2}'",
                                          String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", Del), String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", Al), "AF8257A3-C284-4682-8DB5-6E20AE05C747" );
            DataSet ds = bdBase.bdDataset(conexion, sQuery);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (ds != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TablaVales tv = new TablaVales();
                    tv.NumeroVale = int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["NumeroVale"].ToString());
                    tv.Status = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Status"].ToString();
                    tv.MotivoValeExtraviado = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["MotivoValeExtraviado"].ToString();
                    tv.FechaAsigna =DateTime.Parse( ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["FechaAsigna"].ToString());
                    tv.TiendaAsigna = (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TiendaAsigna"].ToString());
                    tv.AsignadoPor = (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["AsignadoPor"].ToString());

                    tableV.Add(tv);
                    LstTemp = tableV;
                }
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(LstTemp.ToList());
            return json;
        }
```

y éstos son los datos que me arroja el JSON, creo que hasta aquí todo bien
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Aquí mi Aplicación Xamarin Android

```
 public void Rest()
    {
        try
        {
            RestClient client = new RestClient("http://portalclientewa.azurewebsites.net/api/Values/");
            var request = new RestRequest("GetData", Method.GET);
            request.Timeout = 300000;
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddParameter("Del", btnDel.Text);
            request.AddParameter("Al", btnAl.Text);
            //request.AddParameter("llaveEmp", llaveEmp);
            request.AddParameter("id", id);
            var temp = client.Execute(request).Content;
            List<TablaVales> lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TablaVales>>(temp);
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = lst;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
```

Pero en la línea "List lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject>(temp);
                dataGrid.ItemsSource = lst;" me tira el siguiente error:

> "Error converting value
>   "[{"NumeroVale":107,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   {"NumeroVale":43,"Status":"Extraviado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"Se
>   perdió","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":45,"Status":"Extraviado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"Se
>   perdió","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":204,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-06T07:58:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":148,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"}]"  to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AndroidPP.Controller.TablaVales]'.
>   Path '', line 1, position 29775."

¿Alguna idea del por qué manda ese error? o si me pudieran ayudar a encontrar mi error, gracias.

Añado la clase TablaVales

```
public class TablaVales
{ 
        public int NumeroVale { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string MotivoValeExtraviado { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaAsigna { get; set; }
        public string TiendaAsigna { get; set; }
        public string AsignadoPor { get; set; }
}

y cabe mencionar que la clase es igual tanto en la WebApi, como en la AppMóvil
```

Y añado JSON en formato texto

```
[{"NumeroVale":107,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":109,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":119,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:08","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":126,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":108,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":55,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":129,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":102,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":138,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":113,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":121,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:08","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":100,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":105,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":200,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-06T07:58:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":122,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:08","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":201,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-06T07:58:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":116,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":115,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":128,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":123,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:08","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":35,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":52,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":53,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":5,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-09T19:47:28","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":47,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":54,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":111,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":34,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":51,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":104,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":37,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":7,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-09T19:47:28","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":120,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:08","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":31,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":125,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":40,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":136,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":38,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":44,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":32,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":103,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":42,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":114,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":64,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":66,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":67,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":50,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":9,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-09T19:47:29","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":59,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":60,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":41,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":46,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":48,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":49,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":112,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":523,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:38:21","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":507,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:07:59","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":10,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-09T19:47:29","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":101,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":110,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":118,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":144,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":106,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":124,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:08","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":141,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":143,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":142,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":145,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":127,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":117,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":39,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":203,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-06T07:58:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":205,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-06T07:58:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":525,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:38:21","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":513,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:07:59","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":514,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:07:59","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":516,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:38:21","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":515,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:07:59","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":510,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:07:59","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":519,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:38:21","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":512,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:07:59","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":140,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":146,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":151,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":152,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":43,"Status":"Extraviado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"Se perdió","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":45,"Status":"Extraviado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"Se perdió","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":204,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-06T07:58:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":206,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-06T07:58:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":1,"Status":"Cancelado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-09T19:47:28","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":2,"Status":"Cancelado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-09T19:47:28","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":3,"Status":"Cancelado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-09T19:47:28","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":96,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":97,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":4,"Status":"Cancelado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-09T19:47:28","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":6,"Status":"Cancelado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-09T19:47:28","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":8,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-09T19:47:28","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":202,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-06T07:58:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":91,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":92,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":207,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-06T07:58:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":208,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-06T07:58:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":511,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:07:59","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":517,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:38:21","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":167,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":168,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":521,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:38:21","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":522,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:38:21","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":171,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":172,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":161,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":162,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":508,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:07:59","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":509,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:07:59","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":165,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":166,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":155,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":156,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":169,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":170,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":159,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":160,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":149,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":150,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":163,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":164,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":153,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":154,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":137,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":139,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":157,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":158,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":147,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":148,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"}]
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la definición de la clase `TablaVales`? Así como está tu escenario todo parece ser un error de algún convirtiendo algún tipo.

Comment: He editado la pregunta, añadiendo la clase TablaVales, gracias por responder. @Flxtr

Comment: Gracias Óscar ;) ¿de igual forma podrías poner el json en formato texto y no en imagen? Lo voy a tomar para hacer una pequeña prueba.

Comment: Listo @Flxtr, gracias por el tiempo, he añadido el Json en formato texto

Comment: He tomado tu json, lo deserializo a la clase `TablaVales` y no obtengo ningún error, se crea una lista de 134 elementos con los valores tal cual aparecen en el json.

Comment: @Flxtr, no entiendo porque mi aplicación me tira ese error, :( pero si no es error de sintáxis, intentaré buscando alguna otra solución externa al código, de todas formas muchas gracias por el tiempo.

Comment: [Aquí te dejo la muestra](http://rextester.com/MLJX75603), básicamente es el json que tú publicaste, todo parece salir bien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saludos,

Otra alternativa puede ser utilizar la libreria de `System.Net` para la petición al server. Te anexo el ejemplo que utilice para

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<TablaVales>> GetData()
        {
            var url = $"http://portalclientewa.azurewebsites.net/api/Values/GetData?Del=2016-01-01&Al=2017-12-31&id=AF8257A3-C284-4682-8DB5-6E20AE05C747";//Modificar con los valores a enviar, al ser GET pueden ser enviados desde la URL
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
            httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";

            var response = await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
               var json = sr.ReadToEnd();
               var parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json).ToString();
               var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TablaVales>>(parsedJson);
            return data;
            }

        }
```

Otra observación es que al momento de regresar la información de la WebAPI lo haces como `string` y al momento de extraerla del server le coloca secuencias de escape, por lo que cuando intenta hacer el parseo de la información arroja el error, para evitar esto se agrego la linea `var parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json).ToString();` esta para que `Newtonsoft.Json` se encarge de quitar las secuencias de escape a la cadena.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ya tenía quebrándome la cabeza un buen rato, y gracias por las observaciones, de mucha ayuda todo